# How to make a flexible size hash table

Tags: c, hashtable

I would like to use this code which filters a large file. Currently I am hard coding the size of the hash table, assuming the input has 50 million lines. I would like the total number of lines to be 37% of the hash table size. This is achieved currently as 37% of 0x8000000 is roughly 50 million.  However, in practice I won't know the size of the input before I start to process it.  How can I modify the code to automatically adjust the hash table size so that it is of the right size? Speed is also important as the purpose of the filtering is to save time.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

// Should be 37% occupied with 50m entries
#define TABLE_SIZE 0x8000000
#define MASK (TABLE_SIZE - 1)
#define BUFFER_SIZE 16384
#define END_OF_FILE (-1)
#define DEFAULT_VALUE (-1)

typedef struct Row {
  int32_t a;
  int32_t b;
  int32_t t;
} Row;

int32_t hash(int32_t a) {
  return a * 428916315;
}

void insert(Row * table, Row row) {
  long loc = hash(row.a) & MASK; // Entries are hashed on a
  long inc = 0;
  while (inc <= TABLE_SIZE) {
    loc = (loc + inc) & MASK;
    inc++;
    if (table[loc].a == DEFAULT_VALUE) {
      table[loc] = row;
      break;
    }
  }
}

int readChar(FILE * input, char * buffer, int * pos, int * limit) {
  if (*limit < *pos) {
    return buffer[(*limit)++];
  } else {
    *limit = 0;
    *pos = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, input);
    if (*limit < *pos) {
      return buffer[(*limit)++];
    } else return END_OF_FILE;
  }
}

void readAll(char * fileName, Row * table) {
  char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * BUFFER_SIZE);
  int limit = 0;
  int pos = 0;

  FILE * input = fopen(fileName, "rb");

  int lastRead;
  Row currentRow;
  uint32_t * currentElement = &(currentRow.a);

  // As with the Scala version, we read rows with an FSM. We can
  // roll up some of the code using the `currentElement` pointer
  while (1) {
    switch(lastRead = readChar(input, buffer, &pos, &limit)) {
      case END_OF_FILE:
        fclose(input);
        return;
      case ' ':
        if (currentElement == &(currentRow.a)) currentElement = &(currentRow.b);
        else currentElement = &(currentRow.t);
        break;
      case '\n':
        insert(table, currentRow);
        currentRow.a = 0;
        currentRow.b = 0;
        currentRow.t = 0;
        currentElement = &(currentRow.a);
        break;
      default:
        *currentElement = *currentElement * 10 + (lastRead - '0');
        break;
    }
  }
  //printf("Read %d", lastRead);
}

int main() {
  Row* table = (Row*) malloc(sizeof(Row) * TABLE_SIZE);
  memset(table, 255, sizeof(Row) * TABLE_SIZE);

  readAll("test.file", table);

  // We'll iterate through our hash table inline - passing a callback
  // is trickier in C than in Scala, so we just don't bother
  for (size_t i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
    Row * this = table + i;
    if (this->a != DEFAULT_VALUE) {
      // Lookup entries `that`, where `that.a == this.b`
      long loc = hash(this->b) & MASK;
      long inc = 0;
      while (inc <= TABLE_SIZE) {
        loc = (loc + inc) & MASK;
        inc++;
        Row * that = table + loc;
        if ((this->b == that->a) && (0 <= that->t - this->t) && (that->t - this->t < 100)) {
          // Conditions are symmetric, so we output both rows
          printf("%d %d %d\n", this->a, this->b, this->t);
          printf("%d %d %d\n", that->a, that->b, that->t);
        }
        else if (that->b == DEFAULT_VALUE) break;
      }
    }
  }

  free(table);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to reorganize -or grow- your hash table, with e.g. bigger buckets, from time to time or when you have reached some density threshold. In practice that reorganization is almost like making a new hash table and filling it with entries from the old one. You'll probably want something like `newsize = 5*oldsize/4+10;`

Comment: You're not treating hash collisions. You could make each entry in the table be a linked list of `Row`.

Comment: @ericbn It is (or at least it is meant to be) open hashing. This should avoid the problem you mention. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing

Comment: @user2179021, treating collisions as lists in the same bucket can make you keep the table size fixed and let the items grow in another dimension.

Comment: Similar to stackoverflow.com/questions/16907423/converting-static-to-dynamic-hash-table/16908837

Answer (score 0):

Read the first, say, 100 KB of the file, counting its newlines.  Extrapolate from that to guess the total number of newlines you are likely to encounter in the entire file (using the total size which is O(1)).  If the input files are fairly regular, this will give you a guess close enough for the purpose of sizing a hash table.